# vim, ssh и копирование

Tags: vim

По ходу работы нужно часто редактировать файлы прямо на сервере, к которому подключаюсь через `ssh`. `vim` работает точно так же как на основной машине, но возникла проблема с копированием данных (вставкой строк в файл через `vim`) между моей машиной и сервером. Когда я копирую некоторые строки на основной машине, то не могу их вставить в `vim`-е поскольку скопированные данные находятся в недоступном месте (на другой машине). Приходится использовать мышь для вставки (правая кнопка и вставить), но я, думаю, есть фариант получше.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin а вы вопрос читали?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я же прямо после этого термина вставил пояснение - вставка строк vim. В любом случае это "решение" никак сдесь не подходит

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ещё раз: вставить скопированные строки в vim, который открыт через ssh

Comment: скопированные куда? если, например, в один из буферов обмена x-сервера, то вставить их в эмулятор терминала (независимо от того, какая программа там выполняется) можно сочетаниями `shfit+insert` (из буфера выделения) и `shift+ctrl+insert` (из первичного буфера).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin вот это вроде что нужно, после выходных проверю